# How do I link php slim with Ionic

Tags: php, ionic-framework, slim

this is the code in ionic to link to my slim api:

```
    postData(credentials, type){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      let headers = new Headers();
      this.http.post("http://slimapp:8080/api/signup", JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers}).
      subscribe(res =>{
        resolve(res.json());
      }, (err) =>{
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

credentials is my data and type is"signup"

and this is the slim php code tp match the route

```
$app->post('/api/signup', function(Request $request, Response $response){
// my function is here
});
```

when i connect postman with php slim, everything works well, but when i connect it with ionic, this error comes up:
[404]: /api/signup - No such file or directory

This is the error showing on the command prompt where i started the the php server
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRZsD.png)
how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Patrick, welcome to stack overflow. Are you using this on a local environment? Is 8080 available on your server? If you are using a local host, it likely is. If you are running a vm or cloud server you'll likely have to use a reverse proxy on a web server like nginx.

Comment: Hi, I am running it on a local host.
I started the php server by going into slim directory from command prompt and the wrote:
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Then you should be using `this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/signup"`, correct?

Comment: I have mapped 127.0.0.1 to slimapp in hosts. I tested it on POSTMAN, it works fine, but whenever I connect it from ionic, it gives the error:
[404]: /slimapp/api/signup - No such file or directory

I also disabled the securities in chrome for running the ionic web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your error log (usually better to include formatted error messages in your question rather than linking an image) I noticed you're creating the PHP server in the root of the slim framework, but you're not declaring the document root to the `public` directory like in the [documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/).

You should be able to do one of two things:

You can navigate to the `public` directory - `.../htdocs/slimapp/public` - and start the PHP server there - `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080`

Or you can specify the document root of the server (just like in the docs posted) with the `-t` flag.

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php
```

If you run `php --help` you can see all of the flags available with the `php` binary.

```
php --help
...
-S <addr>:<port> Run with built-in web server.
-t <docroot>     Specify document root <docroot> for built-in web server.
...
```